# Child model not saved during seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-1.8.7

I am creating contacts & users in the DB in `seed.rb`. Using the code below, the contact is saved but the child user is not. What am I missing? I've tried with and without the `if` statement, and the user is never saved.

**Models**

```
class Contact < BaseModel
  #...
  has_one :user
end

class User < BaseModel
  #...
  belongs_to :contact
end
```

**Seed**

```
contact = Contact.where({
  :first_name => "Some",
  :last_name  => "Person",
  :email      => "some.person@domain.com",
  :zip        => "12345"}).first_or_initialize
contact.build_user if contact.user == nil
contact.save!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `contact` was not exist then it won't put `contact_id` in user model.

You should first `save` `contact` or used `existing` so rails will automatically put `contact_id` in `user` `model`

Comment: I don't like it, but it works. I'm used to C# (LINQ, EF) where child models are automatically updated w/their parent's ID when the parent is committed to the DB. Thanks!